# KeyPress horizontal navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use left/right arrows to navigate horizontally across my webpage.

Because of Firefox/Chrome handling a default arrow movement differently I had to disable the default movement (Firefox would move it 20px too far right).

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
// space and arrow keys
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
}, false);  
</script>
```

I've then got a Keydown function to move 1980px left/right on keypress. (I coudln't get keypress to work because of blocking the default move)

```
<script>
    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
    var currentx = 0;
    var viewport = 1920;
    var btnright = (+currentx) + (+viewport);
    var btnleft = (+currentx) - (-viewport);

if ( e.which == 37 ) {
    window.scrollTo(btnleft, 0);
    currentx = (+currentx) - (-viewport);
} else if ( e.which == 39 ) {
    window.scrollTo(btnright, 0);
    currentx = (+currentx) + (+viewport);
}
});
</script>
```

I want it to be recurring (the page is 6000px wide) but I want to move 1 panel (1980px) at a time (Update $Current after each move). Eventually so I can navigate the whole page via arrows.

My issue is I can't get the event to trigger more than once, I can only navigate from 0 to 1980. It won't go any further. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think this is a problem of the event being triggered only once (place a console.log debug output at the beginning to _verify_), but rather of you setting `currentx` to `0` again each time the handler is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe stated, your `currentx` variable is being set to `0` each time that the event is triggered. Try moving the `currentx` variable declaration out of the event handler like following:

```
<script>
    var currentx = 0,
        viewport = 1920;
    $(window).keydown(function (e) {
        var btnright = (+currentx) + (+viewport),
            btnleft = (+currentx) - (-viewport);
        if ( e.which == 37 ) {
            window.scrollTo(btnleft, 0);
            currentx = (+currentx) - (-viewport);
        } else if ( e.which == 39 ) {
            window.scrollTo(btnright, 0);
            currentx = (+currentx) + (+viewport);
        }
    });
</script>
```